# Cant access outer tabhost from an inner tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

#### I am trying to make a chat messenger.

I am trying to create a page which has tabs on the bottom and we can navigate to different pages by clicking on the tab.
I can implement this tab properly using the tabhosts widget from android. (I know android doesn't want us to implement bottom based tabs.)

The problem arises when one of the activities which is being opened has another tabhost inside it, that is to say a nested tab implementation.

The activities linked to the inner tabhost overlay on the outer tabhost and I cant click on the outer tabhost once I am on one of the tabs of the inner tabhost.

It is true that the outer tabhost is on a different activity than the inner tabhost.

I have run out of ideas. I need help.

I tried implementing FragmentTabHost also but with the same result. I want a way to access the outer tabhost from the inner tabhost.

**My main activity file which contain the outer tabhost:  Welcome_page.java**

```
    package com.ciaoappskeleton.login;   
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
    import android.app.TabActivity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Resources;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener;
    import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import com.ciaoappskeleton.CallTab;
    import com.ciaoappskeleton.R;
    
    public class Welcome_page extends TabActivity {
        private Context ctx=this;
        TabHost tabHost;
        private Resources res;
        private  LocalActivityManager lam;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome_page);
            
            lam = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
            lam.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
            res=getResources();
            initialize_tabs(); //initialize the tabs        
             
            
            
        }
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
              MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
                return true;
        }
        public void initialize_tabs()
        {
                 
        
            tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            if(tabHost==null)
            {
                Log.i("TABHOST status 1","is null");
                return;
            }

            tabHost.setup(lam);

            
            addTab(R.drawable.nav_phone_big,com.ciaoappskeleton.CallTab.class,"Calls","CALLS"); 
 
 /*
this CallTab.java activity contains another tabhost
*/
            
           addTab(R.drawable.nav_message,com.ciaoappskeleton.MessagesTab.class,"SMS","MESSAGES");
    addTab(R.drawable.nav_coin,CoinDisplay.class,"Credits","CREDITS");
    addTab(R.drawable.nav_gear,GearDisplay.class,"Account","ACCOUNTS");
            
            
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            
            /* just setting the background for the tabs */

            //set the current tab background to ciao background
            int curr_tab=tabHost.getCurrentTab();
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(curr_tab)
            .setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.ciao_color)); // selected
                
            for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.nav_bar_bg));
                                 // unselected
                    }
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(curr_tab)
            .setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.ciao_color)); // selected
            tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.nav_bar_bg));
                                             // unselected
                                }
                      tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                        .setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.ciao_color)); // selected
                    
                }
            });
    
        }
        
        
        private void addTab(int drawableId, Class<?> c, String labelId, String imageText)
        {
            TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec(labelId);
            Intent i1=new Intent().setClass(ctx,c);
            if(drawableId==-1)
            {
                String tabIndicator="NA";
                tab1.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
                tab1.setContent(i1);       
                tabHost.addTab(tab1);
            }
            else
            {
            View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_image_setter, getTabWidget(), false);
            ImageView iv=(ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            iv.setImageResource(drawableId);
            TextView tv=(TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
            tv.setText(imageText);
            tab1.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
            tab1.setContent(i1);       
            tabHost.addTab(tab1);
            }
        
        }
        
        private void set_current_tab(int tabnumber)
        {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabnumber);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onResume();
            lam.dispatchResume();
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPause();
            lam.dispatchPause(isFinishing());
        }
    }
```

**my second activity: CallTab.java**
**I am posting only the important methods, initialization and declaration is been done fine**

```
public void initialize_tabs()
    {
        
        
    
        //tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost=(TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        if(tabHost==null)
        {
            Log.i("TABHOST status","is null");
            return;
        }
        tabHost.setup(lam);

        
        
        addTab(R.drawable.call_tab_keypad,DiallerActivity.class,"Calls","KEYPAD");
        addTab(R.drawable.call_tab_contacts,ContactList.class,"Contacts","CONTACTS");
        
        
        
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
       
        
        //set the current tab background to red background
        int curr_tab=tabHost.getCurrentTab();
    
            
        for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.nav_bar_bg));
                             // unselected
                }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(curr_tab)
        .setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.ciao_color)); // selected
        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.nav_bar_bg));
                                         // unselected
                            }
                  tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab())
                    .setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.ciao_color)); // selected
                
            }
        });

    }
    private void addTab(int drawableId, Class<?> c, String labelId, String imageText)
    {
        TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec(labelId);
        
        Intent i1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),c);
        if(drawableId==-1)
        {
            String tabIndicator="NA";
            tab1.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
            tab1.setContent(i1);       
            tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        }
        else
        {
            
        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_image_setter, tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
        ImageView iv=(ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        iv.setImageResource(drawableId);
        TextView tv=(TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        tv.setText(imageText);
        tab1.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        tab1.setContent(i1);       
        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        }
    
    }
```

XML file for layout: activity_welcome_page.xml

```
    <TabHost
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
              
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>
```

The code is working fine, but when i click on the CONTACTS tab in the inner tabhost, the activity for the displaying the native contacts is loaded , but it is loaded on top of the outer tabhost, so I can see the outer tabhost but I cannot click on it. I want to be able to click on it.

***[Link to images:](http://pbxintern.ciaocrm.com/question/tabhost.html)***

Comment: I have added a link to the images. Please check the image to see what I mean.